# Django Post URL from Browser

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I'm running through the Django tutorials, and I want to figure out how to post changes to a model from the Browser.  Here's the URL:

```
 url(r'^(?P<person_id>\d+)/updatePerson/$', views.updatePerson, name='updatePerson')                       
)
```

Here's the view:

```
def updatePerson(request, person_id):
    p = get_object_or_404(Person, pk=person_id)
#    try:
#        user = p.get(pk=request.POST['name'])
#    except (KeyError, Person.DoesNotExist):
        # Redisplay the poll voting form.
#        return render(request, 'maps/detail.html', {
#            'person': p,
#            'error_message': "This person does not exist",
#        })
    #else:
    p.lat = request.POST['lat']
    p.lon = request.POST['lon']
    p.task = request.POST['task']
    p.save()
        # Always return an HttpResponseRedirect after successfully dealing
        # with POST data. This prevents data from being posted twice if a
        # user hits the Back button.
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('maps:detail', args=(p.id,)))
```

The url I try is:

```
<serveraddress>/maps/1/updatePerson/?lat=20&lon=20&task=hangOut
```

I get this error:

```
    MultiValueDictKeyError at /maps/1/updatePerson/
"Key 'lat' not found in <QueryDict: {}>"
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    <serveraddress>/maps/1/updatePerson/?lat=20
Django Version: 1.5.2
Exception Type: MultiValueDictKeyError
Exception Value:    
"Key 'lat' not found in <QueryDict: {}>"
Exception Location: D:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\utils\datastructures.py in __getitem__, line 295
Python Executable:  D:\Python\python.exe
Python Version: 2.7.5
Python Path:    
['C:\\GXM_LABS\\gxm_maps',
 'D:\\Python\\lib\\site-packages\\setuptools-1.1.3-py2.7.egg',
 'D:\\Python\\lib\\site-packages\\django_evolution-0.6.9-py2.7.egg',
 'D:\\Python\\lib\\site-packages\\south-0.8.2-py2.7.egg',
 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\python27.zip',
 'D:\\Python\\DLLs',
 'D:\\Python\\lib',
 'D:\\Python\\lib\\plat-win',
 'D:\\Python\\lib\\lib-tk',
 'D:\\Python',
 'D:\\Python\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Sat, 7 Sep 2013 16:42:14 -0400
```

Should I be doing a regex in my url definiition to catch the values?  Or am I approaching this incorectly?  I'm working along with the tutorials but modifying them to suit some work I'm doing on the side.  I don't really want a form which users input, as in the long run I'll be posting this data from remote locations (Smartphones), and so a webpage which acually has the ability to submit this data is less interesting to me than the ability to post these changes directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read your query parameters from `request.GET` instead of a `request.POST` since you are making a GET request (see `Request Method: GET` on your error page).

FYI, there is also [request.REQUEST](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.REQUEST) dictionary available:

> For convenience, a dictionary-like object that searches POST first,
>   then GET. Inspired by PHP’s $_REQUEST.

But, it's not a good practice to use it. Better be explicit.

Comment: Thanks, I changed to get, but the queryDict is still empty, which is the underlying issue.  Could you provide more details on how to set that up?